# Confused by SSLCaCertificateFile bundle

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

there's something I can't understand with the SSLCACertificateFile parameter on Apache SSL conf. Put for example I have a ROOT cert "A" that issued an intermediate cert "B". Then, I produced a couple of leaf certificates using B, say "L1", "L2".

Now, according to the documentation, if I want to trust only L1 and L2 I should put "B" and "A" inside a file pointed by SSLCACertificateFile (if I put only certificate "B" Apache gives an unable-to-find-issuer error).

Now, let's produce another certificate, "C", derived from "A" (the root). Would apache trust a peer that's using certificate C? To me, it is a "yes, it will" as Apache will find the issuer of "C" inside the SSLCACertificateFile, it is "A"! But I don't want to trust C, I only want to trust L1 and L2.

Am I missing something?

many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The underlying TLS stack used by Apache is OpenSSL. OpenSSL requires by default a self-signed root certificate as the ultimate trust anchor which means that it is not enough to only add an intermediate CA certificate to the trust store. Since OpenSSL 1.0.2 there is the flag X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN which would make this possible but I don't see it used in the Apache source code.

Thus, if you don't have any control of the root-CA and the intermediate CA there is no way to configure Apache to only trust the intermediate CA but not any other certificates directly or indirectly issued by the root-CA.

But, if you have control over the intermediate CA certificate B (i.e. have the private key) then you can issue another CA certificate B2 with the same subject and private key of B, but make it self-signed. Since subject and public key are the same as in B every certificate issued by B can be successfully validated using B2. And since B2 is self-signed you can put it as the only trust anchor into SSLCACertificateFile with the result that only certificates issued by B/B2 are accepted but not other certificates issued by the root A.

Comment: sorry Steffen, that does not respond to my question. As I told, I actually own RootCA, Intermediate and leaves.

Comment: @MatteoPalma: you say that you *have* a root *certificate*. This does not mean that you own the CA, i.e. that you  are able to issue certificates yourself because this not only requires the certificate but also the matching private key. Even that you produced the certs does not mean that you own the CA because you might have just send CSR to the CA and got certs back. Apart from that this case is covered too starting with *"If you have control over the intermediate CA (i.e. have the private key) ..."*

Comment: right, I wasn't clear: I actually own all the certificates.

A(RootCA, autosigned) -> B(intermediate) -> L1, L2 (leaves).

Now, if I want to trust L1 and L2 I have to build a pem-bundle with A and B, so far so good.

Let's say I produce another certificate C from A and let's imagine that a peers connect to my apache with that certificate, will apache trust it? Yes, it will, but I don't want that behavior! I only want to trust only leaves issued by B

Comment: @MatteoPalma: I've now added more detail to the already outlined approach of creating a new certificate with the same subject and public key as B and explained in more detail how this solves your problem. See edited answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your response. However, coming back to your first hyptotesis (I'm not the owner of the certificates), I'm really really puzzled... I mean, I've an apache and someone ask me to be trusted so he sends me his certificate. If you're correct, I can't trust C without automatically trusting all "sons" of C's issuers! That's unbeliavable, we are hopening a huge hole only to trust a leaf!

Comment: @MatteoPalma: Apache is not designed to just trust a single leaf certificate or to trust only a single sub-CA and this is usually not required to. But, Apache makes at least the client certificate available to the web application so additional checks can be done there. Apart from that I don't like this design decision in OpenSSL either.